# Django inserting large dataset into model - how to delay commit?

Tags: django, django-models

I am working on a project where I need to insert large files into models (sometimes several gigabytes). Because the files can be large the approach I am taking is to read it linewise, and then insert it into the Django model.

However, when an error is encountered in the process, how do I cancel the whole operation? What is the proper way to make sure that the rows are committed after the entire file is processed without errors.

The other alternative is to create all the model objects in one go and insert it in bulk, is this feasible for large datasets? How would it work.

Here's my code:

```
class mymodel(models.Model):
    fkey1 = models.ForeignKey(othermodel1,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fkey2= models.ForeignKey(othermodel2,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field 1= models.CharField(max_length=25,blank=False)
    field 2= models.DateField(blank=False)
    ...
    Field 12= models.FloatField(blank=False)
```

And inserting data into the model from excel:

```
wb=load_workbook(datafile, read_only=True, data_only=True)
ws=wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheetName)
for row in ws.rows:
    if isthisheaderrow(row):
        #determine column arrangement and pass to next
        break
for row in ws.rows:
    if isthisheaderrow(row):
        pass
    elif isThisValidDataRow(row):
        relevantRow=<create a list of values>
        dictionary=dict(zip(columnNames,relevantRow))
        dictionary['fkey1']=othermodel1Object
        dictionary['fkey2']=othermodel2Object
        mymodel(**dictionary).save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I should have looked harder, the commit can be delayed by a decorator `@transaction.atomic`. A more detailed description is given here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/transactions/

The code being:

```
wb=load_workbook(trfile, read_only=True, data_only=True)
ws=wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheetName)
revenueSwitch=True
for row in ws.rows:
    if ifHeaderReturnIndex(row,desiredColumns):
        selectedIndex=ifHeaderReturnIndex(row, desiredColumns)
        outputColumnNames=[row[i].value.replace(" ", "") for i in selectedIndex]
        #output_ws.append(outputColumnNames)
        break
@transaction.atomic
def insertrows():
    for row in ws.rows:
        if ifHeaderReturnIndex(row,desiredColumns):
            pass
        elif isRowValid(row,selectedIndex):
            newrow=[row[i].value for i in selectedIndex]
            dictionary=dict(zip(outputColumnNames,newrow))
            dictionary['UniqueRunID']=run
            dictionary['SourceFileObject']=TrFile
            TransactionData(**dictionary).save()
insertrows()
```

Comment: Just note that it can also be used as a [context manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly) (`with transaction.atomic():`), so no need to create a function just to wrap some code.